# LaTeX code for different choice

Tags: code

Could you please help me to find the LaTeX code that will gives the following result:

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Accepting and upvoting answers (as you did) is the preferred way here to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume, that it is rather similar to the first part of your picture.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\[
5. \left[
\begin{array}{l}
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
\overline{\mathsf{IX}}\uparrow\uparrow\overline{\mathsf{IA}}\\
\overline{\mathsf{JY}}\uparrow\uparrow\overline{\mathsf{JB}}
\end{array}
\right.
\\
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
\overline{\mathsf{IX}}\uparrow\downarrow\overline{\mathsf{IA}}\\
\overline{\mathsf{JY}}\uparrow\downarrow\overline{\mathsf{JB}}
\end{array}
\right.
\end{array}
\right.
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please have a look at [Should we answer really bad questions?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2414) – I think it applies here.

Comment: @doncherry Yes, this question is rather localized, but for me, compared with a question from this night about changing the name of folder from inside TeX file (Removed. Thanks to this society!), it is a pretty good one.